# Like social plugin displays zero likes for any Facebook photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

**Problem**: when [Facebook Like plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) (the like button) is used to allow people to like my facebook posts through my website, it does not display proper number of likes for Photos in my feed. It works only for Status updates.

**Additional information**

All goes well, providing the URL to like from the actual post (eg. http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx/posts/yyyyyyyyy). It displays the like button along with the number of likes that post currently has and allows me to like it. If I'm not logged in to facebook, I'm given a prompt to log in as expected.

However, once that post is of type "photo" (as seen in the graph api) and as such contains a photo, the above method does not work. Even tho the direct link to the post page shows that it has likes, the like button still shows 0 likes, and clicking the like button increases that 0 to 1, but does not increase the like count on that post/photo. It's as if facebook does not connect likes to a post when it contains a photo.

My question is... is it possible to find the proper URL to add to the facebook button in order for it to fetch the right likes from the photo/post (just like it would if there's only a post), and if so, how would I go about finding that URL?

**Way to reproduce**

here is the JSFiddle link which clearly illustrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/HALtb/

Looking for a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in like button that Facebook includes on every FB photo?

Comment: @DonnLee I'm unsure what you mean. Are you talking about the social plug-in provided by Facebook allowing you to show a Like button on your website? If so, that's what the question is about, if not, would you mind explaining what you mean?

Comment: link where the issue is displayed: http://jsfiddle.net/HALtb/

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Like Button social plugin is for liking articles or Open Graph objects by URL
It does not work with content on facebook.com with the exception of Facebook Pages.
It can't be used to like photos, comments, posts, etc. Those can be liked directly via the API with the appropriate permissions from your app's user

Comment: well, as JSFiddle link shows, it works just fine with Facebook post - but not with Photos. Also - I got the URLs in that link from Graph API call: post->actions->like->link. I assumed that's what those actions are for - to provide URL for like button. Please comment on this.

Comment: You were able to get a like button to like a Facebook post permalink? That's not really supposed to work as far as i know, and i wouldn't rely on it

Comment: yes - it works fine for posts - check out JSFiddle page, and click Like button there :)

Comment: here is the graph API query I'm using to get "like" action for the photo object together with the "some" link - which I assumed was the link I can feed to Like button: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=156269277720069%2Fposts%2F%3Flimit%3D1

Comment: As far as I know the intention of that link is that you'd use it as a link to bring the user to somewhere they can like the content, not as a way of liking the content via the API